# How to include custom headers in rmarkdown with fancyhead

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pdflatex

I am trying to generate a PDF document with R Markdown and want to set a custom header for the first page. I copied a very simple code from the internet that looks as follows:

```
---
header-includes:
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
output: pdf_document
---


\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[L]{my header}
  \fancyfoot[C]{my footer}
}


some text

\newpage

some text
```

when I knit the pdf, it generates a pdf doc with the text, but without a header and a page number in the footer... does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a custom pagestyle:

```
---
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{graphicx}
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \input{preamble}  
  - \pagestyle{mystyle}
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
---

some text

\newpage

some text
```

with `preamble.tex`:

```
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[L]{my header}
  \fancyfoot[C]{my footer}
}
```